# Pandas loading the entire text file with tablular data into one column

Tags: python, pandas

Abaqus software generated a peculiar output text file(first image) with spaces and indents. When I tried to read the text file into pandas as tabular data with two columns using read_csv or read_table, it read the entire file into a single column (second image). However, I tried using delim_whitespace as an argument to remove the space but it read the first column in the text file to the index column of the Pandas data frame.

How to solve this problem efficiently so as I can handle hundreds of such files with relative ease.

[image: text file]
[image: pandas dataframe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `index_col=False` in [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) suggests that you can force Pandas not to use the first column as the index.

```
pandas.read_csv('file_name',index_col=False,delim_whitespace=True)
```